# Where are committed files stored on the SVN server file system?

Tags: svn

I have SVN set up and working properly.I can access it via

> http://domain/home/svn/repo/trunk
>   and I have pulled and committed code with STS. However, if I SSH to the `/home/svn/repo/trunk` directory, I don't see any files other than the ones made on creation of the repository.

Where are my committed files stored?

Comment: Why are you trying to access the files without going through SVN?

Comment: I'm not.  I was just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SVN repository itself doesn't contain the files in the format that they were committed in.

Instead, the repository's storage uses either FSFS or BDB as storage - most likely for a modern repository, the FSFS format is used.

You probably shouldn't be mucking around much with the files in the repository itself; it's very easy to blow things up, and most cases where you need to work with the repository directly should be handled in the `svnadmin` command.

If you're just needing the contents of the repository locally on the server, use `svn checkout file:///home/svn/repo/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was really just curious.  I am using Subclipse to access the repository.

Comment: Are the file contents stored within revision files within the db/revs directory in the Subversion repo? I have found references to file names in those, but the contents, I'm not sure. I am also curious.